# What's good practice for archiving a portion of your unused code to be pulled back in later if needed?

Tags: django, git, archiving

We have a lot of small usually one-of projects that all get put as apps inside of a Django project, and I'd like to remove the them from the code to keep it clean, and also to not have to worry about year old projects when doing upgrades to our existing codebase.

Should I just flat out do a `git rm src/clients/my_project/` (and remove all references) together with a `git commit -m "Removed my_project"`. It seems like it would be less obvious that a whole project had been removed if it's just another commit message and would disappear in the noise.

In a few cases we want to recover an old codebase as some clients requests their projects to be re-run or we are doing an adaptation upon something already existing, but definitely in the majority of cases. How do I make it reasonable and obvious there's an old project that can be recovered?

I suppose one solution would be to change to having one git repo per-project, however these projects are very small and doesn't seem to warrant the overhead of setting up github, jenkins and the servers for the deploys etc.

Have anyone solved this in their own organisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably is a good idea to use a separate repo per project. You get much cleaner histories, you don't have to worry about checking out lots of code for projects that are irrelevant, and it's just generally more flexible.

That said, to solve your immediate problem of losing the projects in the noise, you could create a tag for every deletion.

```
git commit -m 'Removed my_project'
git tag -a deletes/my_project -m 'Deletion of my_project'
```

This way you can see all the project deletions in your tag list, and you can find them again easily if you need to reference the project (just remember to look at the parent of `deletes/my_project` to actually get that project's code).

Answer (score 0):

"Small one off projects" sounds like a perfect candidate for topic branches. Especially if they share lots of common code with your main projects. Branches are what git is really good at.

Branching off small projects means you can use the full power of git to manage your projects. You can easily merge or rebase related bug fixes from your main projects into your small projects. You can easily diff between projects. You can branch off a sub-project from a similar project. And if a project turns out to be useful you can merge it back to your master branch.

Also, it makes it easy to deploy projects independently. Just check out the different projects to different servers (or different vhosts on the same server).

When a project becomes big enough to warrant its own repo you can easily convert that branch into its own repo by cloning it again. If you don't want the old history you can get rid of it by either cloning with depth 1 or squashing its history.

Comment: I think I was unclear on something. All of these small projects run inside of a single Django instance, they run separately but rather have separate URL's like http://www.example.org/proj1, http://www.examplre.org/proj2. The reason why I mentioned jenkins is that if proj1 changes, it should cause the whole Django project to rebuild and deploy, so I would need to setup another jenkins trigger and distribute another deploy key for each small project (although I suppose I could streamline that more than it is today).

Comment: I mean they **don't** run separately. I wish I could edit posts past 10 minutes. :)